# Difficulty installing MVC 3 after uninstalling MVC 4 RC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Started a new project recently and planned to use MVC 4. Made the mistake of installing MVC 4 RC without installing MVC 3 first.

After reading about issues other users have had, uninstalled MVC 4 and tried to install MVC3.

I Used the platform installer to install MVC 3 but repeatedly ran into some error message about some part of MVC 3 failed to install (details report of platform installer was not helpfull).

I uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio 2010 Enterprise, and attempted to install MVC 3 twice. Second time just to show someone else the error.

I tried installing a 3rd time so I could copy the error to Stack Overflow for insight.

Shockingly, this time success.

On the one hand I'm glad to have a "successfull" install, on the other hand I'm nervous that something may still be amiss.

I know I'm not giving much to go on, but I was wondering if anyone else has run into this sequence or type of problem? I know Microsoft developers watch this site. Can anyone point out any other steps that may be needed to "clean" MVC 4 RC from my environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

while installing MVC 4 a newer version of Nuget gets installed in your system and this prevents the installation of MVC 3 from being successful. So once you uninstall this version of Nuget from add/remove programs you can successfully install MVC 3 while MVC 4 remains.

Comment: this was the MVC 4 Release Candidate. We had scaffolding and EF integration errors. We read that MVC 3 projects often "broke" with MVC 4 also present. So removing MVC 4 was important to do BEFORE installing MVC 3.

Comment: but this was good insight about Nuget. You have my +1. Hope it makes you more active on over-stack!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, there were no other adverse affects.

After MVC 4 was uninstalled, took 3 tries to install MVC 3. But after more than 5 weeks of development no obvious problem emerged.

Clear lesson is to install MVC 3 BEFORE installing MVC 4.